# Preventing TabBar to go into SubVC instantly

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarController that embeds into TabBar's SubViewController. The TabBarVC is the initial page. In TabBarController's `viewDidLoad()`, I am making an authentication check and if user is not logged in, push segue to LoginVC.

```
   TaBBarVC -> LoginVC
      |
 TabBarSubVC
```

-*TabBarController*:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.hidden = true
    checkAuth()
}

func checkAuth() {
    if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {

    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("TabBarToLogin", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

However, as this call doesn't respond instantly, the TabBarSubVC's `viewDidLoad` executes directly. It shows the view and when the response comes, the pushes segue. I don't want the SubView to open until I tell it to. Is there a way of achieving it?

What is the proper way of preventing the SubVC to run while doing the authentication check?

Comment: You either need to check the login state in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and modify the root view accordingly or display a different initial view (perhaps one that mirrors the launch image) that then segues to either the login or tab bar vc

Comment: Thanks a lot. Which idea is a better approach though?

Comment: I would probably go with the second as it requires less code.  In your `viewDidLoad` for the new initial view controller you can check your login status and the simply perform the required segue.